How do I calculate this Riemann integral problem?
Consider f(x)=1/x over the interval [1,4]. Let P be the partition consisting of the points{1,3/2,2,4} 7.2.  The Definition of the Riemann Integral223(a) Compute L(f,P),U(f,P), and U(f,P)−L(f,P).(b) What happens to the value of U(f,P)−L(f,P) when we add the point 3 to the partition?(c) Find a partition P′ of [1,4] for which U(f,P′)−L(f,P′)<2/5
Hi, please help. I graphed 1/x,  from [1,4],evaluated f(P) = the set 1,2/3, 1/2,1/4. I know the sup(f) = 1 and the inf(f) is 1/4. I am not sure how to calculate L(f,P), U(f,P) and U-L. Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

This looks like you copied and pasted from a PDF to the input box on this site. Can you please reformat it to make it readable?

Let's say you have a partition $P = \{t_0, ...t_n\} \subset[a,b]$ and let $m_i = inf\{f(x) | x \in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]\}$ and $M_i = sup\{f(x) | x \in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]\}$. Then $U(f,P)$ (upper) and $L(f,P)$ (lower) are defined as it follows:
$$
U(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i(t_{i}-t_{i-1})
$$
$$
L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(t_{i}-t_{i-1})
$$
Now, if we come back to your problem, our partition is $P = \{1,3/2,2,4\}$, then:
$m_1 = inf\{f(x) | x \in [1,3/2]\} = 2/3$, $M_1 = sup\{f(x) | x \in [1,3/2]\} = 1$
$m_2 = 1/2$, $M_2 = 2/3$
$m_3 = 1/4$, $M_3 = 1/2$
Let's compute $U(f,P)$:
$$
U(f,P)= \sum_{i=1}^3 M_i(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) = (1)(3/2-1) + (2/3)(2-3/2) +(1/2)(4-2) 
$$
We can sum it all up to get $U(f,P) = 11/6$. $L(f,P)$ is done similarly and the substraction is easy. For $U(f,P')−L(f,P')<2/5$ you just need to find a partion big enough.
